# Editext and Keyboard overlapping new entries to the recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm trying to create a notes app where user can enter notes one after the other quickly by pressing done on their keyboard without having to press the editText again for every entry

The layout is a Constraint Layout.

I constrained a editText below the recyclerview

I want my edit text and the last element inserted to be seen on the screen always when entering new entries

the problem happens when I add entries to the recycler view after a certain point my editText start overlapping over the new entries

only after I exit the keyboard I'm able to see the new entries

and When I click on the editText again after.. the keyboard layout covers the latest entries

Here is a quick gif of my problem

[image: gif describing my problem]

This overlap didnt occur on a emulated device running lollipop (api 21)

but it happens on emulated devices api 24 and api 30

And If it's possible I would also like to add animations to slide the editText up/down when elements in recyclerview gets added/deleted.

Here is the layout code of the navigationview

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="80dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hello_tv"
                    style="@style/titles"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="HELLO,"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username_tv"
                    style="@style/titles"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="USER"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/hello_tv"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/hello_tv"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hello_tv" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                    android:background="#4E4C4C"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_lists_title_tv"
                    style="@style/titles"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:text="My Lists"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_lists_rv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_lists_title_tv"
                    tools:itemCount="15"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/navigation_body_item_layout" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/nav_add_list_til"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="#00ffffff"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:hint="add new list"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_lists_rv">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/nav_add_list_et"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Update (1) :-

I fixed the problem by programmatically scrolling the recyclerview every time I add a new entry.

But no luck on animating editTxt sliding when adding or deleting elements from the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

on AndroidManifest.xml add   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` inside your `<activity>` tag  for example :

```
        <activity
            android:name=".yourActivityName"
            ...
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```